# Add Gradient to UILabel text in Swift 4

Tags: text, uilabel, gradient, ios11, swift4

I'm trying to add gradient to a text in UILabel in table view cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, with the following code:

```
cell.cellLabel.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "gradientText"))
```

where "gradientText" is a png file of a gradient required & textColor is the UILabel in the cell. But the text color remains to be the default color. Can I achieve it without using any third party code.

Comment: Your can follow this way for UILabel too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76021083/7385095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516113/how-to-fix-the-gradient-on-text-when-using-an-image-in-swift-as-the-gradient-re)

```
extension UILabel {
    func setTextColorToGradient(image: UIImage) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
        image.draw(in: bounds)
        let myGradient = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: myGradient!)
    }
}
```

You can use like this :

```
cell.cellLabel.setTextColorToGradient(image: UIImage(named: "gradientText")!)
```